# hide elements if too small without js

Tags: css, dynamic, size

I like to hide content, if the window size falls below a minimum size. I found an example (http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/), but I could not find out, why it works.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box left">foo1</div>
    <aside class="box right">foo2</aside>
</div>
```

The goal is, if the width of container falls below a specified minimum size aside will be hidden. That should work without javascript, just using css.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for is "CSS Media Queries".

Checkout this article for more information: http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

This example would accomplish what you are looking for with only CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  aside { 
    display:none;
  }
}
```

[You might also check out twitter bootstrap to see how this is used to make responsive grid systems and classes that hide elements in specific contexts](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)

Comment: note that per [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271818/media-query-like-behaviour-on-width-of-a-specific-div), you can't use media queries to target div widths, which is more precisely what the asker is looking for.

Comment: Asker in this specific question specified window size, which meant media queries were the relevant answer.

Comment: "if the width of container falls below a specified minimum size aside will be hidden." is the question text.  media queries can be used, but it would be necessary to figure out the ratio between the window size and the container.  I agree that media queries are the way to go, just it is slightly more complicated than just media queries