# override @media screen rules for a specific div?

Tags: html, css

so I get a piece  HTML from an RSS feed and include it inside a `div` on my web page, the prob is; the default inline styling for that set of HTML is being overridden by the rules in the `@media` styling.

Is there a way I can ignore that styling for this div specifically?

Comment: Close voted, not enough information provided.

Comment: what more could you possibly need?

Comment: Some code to work with and/or a live example

Comment: I don't see any need for code here. He asks if he can, in general, override the styles, given in @media query for a specific element of the page.

Comment: @knitevision why doesn't he just try then?

Comment: Try what? @DarkAshelin

Comment: Essentially, maybe he's just looking for the `:not()` selector?

Comment: We need the complete question please. Include css / markup / example. The OP is in chat and the requirements he is stating differ from this question. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15876739#15876739

Comment: Well, actually, this is a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271818/media-query-like-behaviour-on-width-of-a-specific-div

Comment: @knitevision if he doesn't present code, the question doesn't demonstrate minimal understanding need, which I think a question must meet: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @knitevision sounds like a different problem. Your linked question is about making a media query relative to a div instead of viewport. This question here is just about overriding styles given in the media query.

Comment: We should end the discussion here, this question won't have a good solution until OP shows some efforts from his side, else he will get the answers which are just like shooting blindly

Comment: this is a general question. . .I can give example code, but it would be unrelated to the question guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah,

Give a class attribute to your divs, then apply a different class or ID to the div you don't want to be styled.